# Query Joining from the same table 3 times with separate where clauses optimisation

Tags: sql

I Have a query to report the stats of people completing tasks, I need to count from when they was allocated a task from one table to when the they put the task into other statuses in another table.

I have a working solution but it feels inefficient to use 3 joins from the same table.

```
select AvergaeTimeToAccept = AVG(times.TimeToAccept)
      ,AvergaeTimeToStart = AVG(times.TimeToStart)
      ,AvergaeTimeToComplete = AVG(times.TimeToComplete)
from(
    select allocations.PersonGUID, allocations.TaskID1
            ,TimeToAccept = DATEDIFF(s,AllocatedTime ,AcceptedTime)
            ,TimeToStart = DATEDIFF(s,AcceptedTime ,StartedTime)
            ,TimeToComplete = DATEDIFF(s,StartedTime ,CompletedTime)
    from(
        select    TaskID1
                , AllocatedTime = Min(TimeSet)
                , PersonGUID
        from      TaskStatusHistories h  
        join      TaskStatuses t  
            on  StatusID = t.ID  
        join      TaskAllocationHistories th  
            on  h.TaskStatusHistoryID = th.TaskStatusHistoryID  
            And Status = 'Allocated' 
        group by TaskID1, th.PersonGUID
    ) as allocations
    Join( 
        select   TaskID1
               , AcceptedTime = Min(TimeSet)
               , PersonGUID
        from    TaskStatusHistories h  
        join    TaskStatuses t  
            on  StatusID = t.ID  
        join    TaskResponses r  
            on  TaskID1 = r.TaskID 
            and r.ResponseID = StatusID  
            And Status = 'Accepted'
            group by TaskID1, r.PersonGUID
    ) as accepted
        on allocations.TaskID1 = accepted.TaskID1 
        and allocations.PersonGUID= Accepted.PersonGUID
    Join(
        select   TaskID1
               , StartedTime = Min(TimeSet)
               , PersonGUID
        from TaskStatusHistories h  
        join TaskStatuses t  
            on  StatusID = t.ID  
        join TaskResponses r  
            on TaskID1 = r.TaskID 
            and r.ResponseID = StatusID  
            And Status = 'Started'
        group by TaskID1, r.PersonGUID
    ) as started
        on accepted.TaskID1 = started.TaskID1
    Join(
        select   TaskID1
                , CompletedTime = Min(TimeSet)
                , PersonGUID
        from TaskStatusHistories h  
        join TaskStatuses t  
            on  StatusID = t.ID  
        join TaskResponses r  
            on TaskID1 = r.TaskID 
            and r.ResponseID = StatusID  
            And Status = 'Completed'
        group by TaskID1, r.PorterGUID) 
    as completed
        on accepted.TaskID1 = completed.TaskID1
) times
```

How can I speed up this query?

Comment: Perhaps skip the joins, and do a group by instead at the end, with conditional aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. And I think, `allocations.PersonGUID = statuses.PersonGUID` predicate should be added.

```
select 
    AvergaeTimeToAccept = AVG( DATEDIFF(s,AllocatedTime ,statuses.AcceptedTime) ),
    AvergaeTimeToStart = AVG( DATEDIFF(s,AcceptedTime ,statuses.StartedTime) ),
    AvergaeTimeToComplete = AVG( DATEDIFF(s,StartedTime ,statuses.CompletedTime) )
from (
    select   
        TaskID1, 
        PersonGUID, 
        Min(TimeSet) AS AllocatedTime 
    from TaskStatusHistories h  
        join TaskStatuses t on StatusID = t.ID  
        join TaskAllocationHistories th on h.TaskStatusHistoryID = th.TaskStatusHistoryID  
                And Status = 'Allocated' 
    group by TaskID1, th.PersonGUID ) as allocations
Join(
    select 
        TaskID1, 
        PersonGUID,  
        Min(CASE WHEN Status='Accepted' THEN TimeSet END ) AS AcceptedTime,
        Min(CASE WHEN Status='Started' THEN TimeSet END ) AS StartedTime,
        Min(CASE WHEN Status='Completed' THEN TimeSet END ) AS CompletedTime
    from TaskStatusHistories h  
        join TaskStatuses t  on  StatusID = t.ID  
        join TaskResponses r on TaskID1 = r.TaskID and r.ResponseID = StatusID  
                And Status IN( 'Accepted', 'Started', 'Completed')
    group by TaskID1, r.PersonGUID ) as statuses
        on allocations.TaskID1 = statuses.TaskID1
            AND allocations.PersonGUID = statuses.PersonGUID
```

Comment: This works very well, Much nicer structure thanks, It still takes just over a second on 100,000 records am i likely to see any further improvement without reducing result set?